# lapply(tk_choose.files) customize file selection window

Tags: r, xlsx, lapply, filechooser

I want to create a dialogue window that will pop up and the user will be able to choose multiple xlsx files and return a list of the data. I found that a possible solution is to use `tk_choose.files`, but it gives me an error.

```
choose.dir(getwd(), "Choose a suitable folder")

library(xlsx)
library(rJava)
library(xlsxjars)
library(tcltk)

#get file names
f = list.files("./")

#read files
dat = lapply(f, function(i){
  x = tk_choose.files(caption="Choose your files"), read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1, sheetName = NULL, startRow = 24,
                endRow = NULL, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = FALSE)
  #return columns with names and colors
  x = x[, c(2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19), drop=FALSE]
  #return the data
  x
})
```

> Error: unexpected ',' in:
>   "dat = lapply(f, function(i){
>   x = tk_choose.files(caption="Choose your files"),"

I know there is a mistake in the syntax, but I'm very new to R and don't know how to write it properly.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you want to select files with `tk_choose.files` within the `lapply` which already has gotten a list of file names in `f`?

Comment: The calls to `library(rJava)` and `library(xlsxjars)` are superfluous as `library(xlsx)` invokes all dependencies

Comment: Uwe Block, yes that's what i want to do. Didn't know that about library(xlsx), thanks

Comment: If you want to save yourself from future headaches, please, use the `R` assignment operator `<-` not the ambiguous `=` (see [Chapter 8.2.26
"= is not a synonym of <-" of Patrick Burns' "The R Inferno"](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)).

Comment: I tried using `<-` instead of `=`, but i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something along

```
#read files
dat <- lapply(tk_choose.files(caption="Choose your files"), function(i) {
  x <- read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1, sheetName = NULL, startRow = 24,
                 endRow = NULL, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = FALSE)
  #return columns with names and colors
  x <- x[, c(2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19), drop = FALSE]
 #return the data
  x
})
```

By this, the user selects a the files before stepping through the vector of file names in the `lapply` call.

You got the error because you have two statements on one line separated by a comma. Your code:

```
x = tk_choose.files(caption="Choose your files"), read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1, sheetName = NULL, startRow = 24,
            endRow = NULL, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = FALSE)
```

The first statement is

```
x = tk_choose.files(caption="Choose your files")
```

which assigns the chosen file names(s) to variable `x`. Then you have a comma and a second statement

```
read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1, sheetName = NULL, startRow = 24,
          endRow = NULL, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = FALSE)
```

whose result is not stored at all.

Comment: That works, thanks! One more question: after I return the data and apply some functions, I want to return the output to a customized directory. When the output directory is not customized, for example `pth <- "C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/test/`, i can see the output. When i tried `pth <- choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Choose the output path")` though, I can't see anything. No errors, but no output also. Do you know why?

Comment: @joasa Not sure what you mean. Is this a complete new question? Please, enter a new question with a minimal working example so that others can reproduce the issue - Thank you.